# Implicit Calculation in Function

Tags: function, implicit, modelica, dymola

I use pointers in component models to pass information (property data) to functions, in which further quantities are calculated explicitely.

One of the quantities has to be calculated implicitely. However, as well known, implicit equations can't be calculated in functions.

My solution is to call a model from the function and  to pass the information of the pointer via the function to the model. However, as well known, models can't be called from functions.

So my question is: Does anyone has an idea for a work around?

(btw: There is no possibility to change the component models in such a way, to directly call the further model, because I would have to change a lot of models.)

In the component model I am calling

`Fluidmodel A(fluidpointer, temperature(p=pressure,h=enthalpy))`

The component model calls the fluid model `Fluidmodel A` which contains the function `temperature`. In the function `temperature` the temperature can be calculated explicite.

As I want to solve an implicit function I would need to call another model helper within `temperature`.

As this is not possible I am looking for a workaround. (Using `fluidpointer` which is surpassed to `Fluidmodel A` would not help as I would have to change components models to be able to call helper within `Fluidmodel A`.)

Comment: Do you have a concrete minimal example demonstrating this, and showing which aspects you don't want (or can't) change? This could help folks to suggest approaches to solve this.

Comment: Hi there, would you mind adding your comment information to your question, perhaps with an Edit: at the start. This is so people can read all the important information inside your question, instead of having to read comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an implicit calculation in a function, but you can use the return value from a function, even the complete function call if it is scalar, in an implicit equation and it will just be solved, so normally this is no problem at all to express in Modelica. Simply write it in the model. The function return value will then just be part of a non-linear equation system, you don't have to worry about it other than the following:

- Your function needs to return numerically sensible values everywhere, where it can be called by a non-linear solver, which can be far from the solution. That can be a challenge for fluid properties and might require you to implement extrapolation inside the function and asserts outside the function to handle.
- It will be more efficient if you provide a derivative function to return the gradient of the function w.r.t. the inputs so that the solver can use an analytic Jacobian. Check out the specification about the derivative annotation. If you are very lucky, your tool can generate those automatically.